# CodenameOne IOS app crashing due to null threadsToDelete

Tags: codenameone

I have a codenameOne app that works fine on Android but occasionally crashes on iOS.

From xcode it looks like its failing at:

```
JAVA_VOID java_lang_Thread_releaseThreadNativeResources___long(CODENAME_ONE_THREAD_STATE, JAVA_LONG nativeThreadId) {
for(int i = 0 ; i < NUMBER_OF_SUPPORTED_THREADS ; i++) {
    if(threadsToDelete[i] != 0 && threadsToDelete[i]->threadId == nativeThreadId) {
        free(threadsToDelete[i]->blocks);
        free(threadsToDelete[i]->threadObjectStack);
        free(threadsToDelete[i]->callStackClass);
        free(threadsToDelete[i]->callStackLine);
        free(threadsToDelete[i]->callStackMethod);
        free(threadsToDelete[i]->pendingHeapAllocations);
        free(threadsToDelete[i]);

        threadsToDelete[i] = 0;
        break;
    }
}
```

}

in nativeMethods.m. It says threadsToDelete is null in that if statement. This seems to happen when I open a new form showing a picture, then switch back to the original form. I do start a new thread to save certain details to amazon. But it doesn't crash everytime. 
[image]

Comment: On which line above does it say that it's 0? Is the entry within the array 0 or is the array `threadsToDelete` itself 0? Is there a way you can reproduce this with a simple test case?

Comment: Line 3, the if statement, threadsToDelete[i] is null. I don't know how to reproduce with a simple test case sorry. I don't know enough about what this code is doing to figure out which part of my app could be causing it. Like I said, I start a few threads for various background tasks. If you have any ideas on what could cause this, I may be able to figure out a test case?

Comment: if `threadsToDelete[i]` == 0 this is fine as that is a valid state tested here. If `threadsToDelete` is 0 that would be a problem. Can you post the stack trace from xcode?

Comment: @shaiAlmog I am so completely new to xcode I can't even figure out how to get a copy of the stacktrace sorry, but I've added a screenshot if that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue in Github [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/9b33a8f60aba5541249a2ffc82597ddab496fb3f).  It will be included with the next build server update (probably today, possibly next week).

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate all your help.